# Error on ItemDataBound on repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemdatabound

I am working with repeaters in asp.net and keep getting this error when I try to debug.  I have multiple repeaters in this application already and those repeaters are all working correctly with no problem.  when I went to add this one to the top of the page this error appears.  The error does not appear when I get rid of the on item data bound section.  I do have a method set up in c# with the correct name for this.

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to     service this request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a
>   definition for 'rptCert_ItemDataBound' and no extension method
>   'rptCert_ItemDataBound' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 55: 
Line 56:         <b>Certifications</b><br />
Line 57:         <asp:Repeater ID="rptCert" runat="server" 
Line 58:             onitemdatabound="rptCert_ItemDataBound">
Line 59:             <HeaderTemplate>



<asp:Repeater ID="rptCert" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCert_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px"></td>
                    <td width="30px"></td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAcct"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCert"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Have you compiled your web app? Does your method have the right parameter types?

Comment: Did you perchance copy your default.aspx code behind page into a new file?

Comment: @JoelEtherton That can't be it.  the code is on the default.aspx.cs page with all the other methods that work if I get rid of the `onitemdatabound="rptCert_ItemDataBound"` section

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function `rptCert_ItemDataBound`

Did you delete your code behind or not include that function -- maybe you have an error and it does not compile?

---

Because your header says this:

```
Inherits="Interaction_Experience_Update._Default"
```

The object at `Inherits="Interaction_Experience_Update._Default"` has to have a function with this template:

```
void rptCert_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
  {}
```

Comment: on the backend I have this `protected void rptCert_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {}`

Comment: well the run-time linker is not finding it.

Comment: Did it compile?  I would expect it to be `Object sender...` Since caps matter in C#

Comment: Any ideas as to why?  I have tried deleting it and creating it new, with different names, and copying a repeater that already works but just changing the name and still it doesnt work

Comment: Yes when I build and rebuild and clean the solution they all complete with no problems.  I just tried switching to captial 'O' still got same error

Comment: You have to show us the code -- I can't guess.  Are you getting any errors on build?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Interaction_Experience_Update._Default" %>

Comment: @Hogan that is the auto-generated designer class.  I know I'm not supposed to edit that.  When I go to the designer class and look at the dropdown of tool names and methods I see rptCert and the item data bound method.  When i click the method it takes me to the method on the .cs code page i have already created.  So it looks like it should be linking up

Comment: Two Ideas, 1) What happens when you remove the protected keyword from procedure declaration? 2) Are you compiling with optimization?  If so this could fail because an empty function might optimize to inline and you can have an inline delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I called one of my friends on my phone and he said thinks I was stuck in an infinite loop.  I stopped the ASP.NET Developer Server by right-clicking on the icon on the lower right side of my screen.  After stopping that it began to run correctly.  Pulling the data and hitting the event code.